# Firebase cloud function only triggering when I manually add data to firestore from console

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My function does not trigger when I add things to firestore programatically, it only executes when I add data manually from the console.

Here's my function:

```
exports.updateFirestoreStatistics = functions.firestore.document('applications/2018/all/{app}').onWrite(change => {
  let ref = db.collection('statistics').doc('2018');
  let t = db.runTransaction(transaction => {
    return transaction.get(ref).then(doc => {
      let updatedAppCount = doc.data().applications + 1
      return transaction.update(ref, {applications: updatedAppCount});
    })
  }).then(() => console.log('Stat updated! ')).catch(err => console.log('An error occured ', err));
});
```

Comment: Is `{app]` a document or a collection?

Comment: @RodrigoMata a document

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to add "things" programmatically? And after you add the data programmatically, does it show in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You should return the Promise returned by the asynchronous [`runTransaction()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#runTransaction) method.

If you don't do so, it may happen that the Cloud Functions instance running your function shuts down before your function successfully execute the transaction.

I would suggest you watch the 2 following videos from the Firebase team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk

Comment: Hi @kumail. Did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?